# How to choose assymetry for KL divergence?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, applications, entropy

I have two 2D probability distributions of eye movements of two different images. Suppose I call the first distribution of Image 1: $P$, and the second distribution of image 2: $Q$. Since KL-divergence is assymetric, how should I know which way to compute $D_{KL}(P|Q)$, or $D_{KL}(Q|P)$ ? Semantically, what is this difference? And finally, how should I interpret the value that KL-Divergence returns to me? I would know how to interpret say, euclidean distances, or manhattan distances between the heatmaps (and I could have a fair idea of what is 'big' and 'small'), are there any general rules of thumb for KL-divergence, that might depend for example on vector dimensionality?

I'm attaching the sample data, so you guys can have a look. Note: Image 1, and Image 2 look very alike, but they are actually different! (The Computer Mouse is present in one case, and it is absent in the other)

Image 1:

[image: Image 1]

Image 2:

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use KL-Divergence, instead of another metric (e.g., total variation, or $\ell_2$, or Hellinger)? (if you have a particular reason for this but the asymmetry has no foundation, you can always look at the [symmetrised version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Symmetrised_divergence))

Comment: I was going for KL-Divergence since it is usually seen in the visual psychology literature as a way of comparing heatmaps. However, I don't think there is a 'true standard'. I do ideally for this case want to have a metric that is invariant to translation/alignment (even though they look pretty aligned). I will read on these other metrics. Thanks!